# Can't properly calculate column width

Tags: tables, lengths

Please consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|p{40mm}|p{100mm}|}
    Company & Head Quarters\\
    \hline
    Foo Bar Company  & New York, New York, United States of America\\
    Bar Brothers     & London, United Kingdom\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some companies}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|p{40mm}|p{50mm}|p{50mm}|}
    Fruit            & Likeability & Street names\\
    \hline
    Pears            & meh         & Baker Street\\
    Apples           & meh         & Harbour Street\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some random stuff}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Something strange is going on: in Table 2, the middle and right column is set to have a size of 50 mm each. Yet, they are not as wide as the upper table, which is 100 mm. Why is this? What can I do to make sure Table 2 is as wide as Table 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

By default each column is surrounded by one `\tabcolsep` on each side (resulting in two such spaces when two columns are side by side). You have to consider those in your code and subtract them from your width.

Just as a side note: You can control those spaces using `@{<stuff-between-columns}` in between two column specifiers. So `@{\hspace*{0.5\tabcolsep}` would result in half a `\tabcolsep` there (note that the `@{}` syntax overwrites both spaces, so if the above is used in between two columns there'll be a total of only `0.5\tabcolsep`).

Also note that if you use vertical rules and the package `array` the vertical rules do take some space (without `array` they result in the same horizontal space as without). Therefore if you use `array` you'd have to subtract an additional `\arrayrulewidth` in the first column, resulting in: `{|p{40m}|p{dimexpr50mm-\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|p{\dimexpr50mm-\tabcolsep\relax}|}` as the column specification. (or `0.5\arrayrulewidth` in both to get even results)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{40mm}|p{100mm}|}
    Company & Head Quarters\\
    \hline
    Foo Bar Company  & New York, New York, United States of America\\
    Bar Brothers     & London, United Kingdom\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{40mm}|*2{p{\dimexpr50mm-\tabcolsep\relax}|}}
    Fruit            & Likeability & Street names\\
    \hline
    Pears            & meh         & Baker Street\\
    Apples           & meh         & Harbour Street\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tabularx` so you won't have to make calculations with `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`, and the tables won't overflow into the margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.57\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.43\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}
    Company & Head Quarters\\
    \hline
    Foo Bar Company & New York, New York, United States of America\\
    Bar Brothers & London, United Kingdom\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some companies}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}X|*{2}{>{\hsize=1.075\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}}
    Fruit & Likeability & Street names\\
    \hline
    Pears & meh & Baker Street\\
    Apples & meh & Harbour Street\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some random stuff}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very interesting solution but how are the factors controlling \hsize defined? for example in `\hsize=0.57\hsize` and `\hsize=1.43\hsize\arraybackslash`

Comment: @Alfonso: It's a quite simple equation that one has to solve: the values of the `\hsize`s  have to be proportional to 40 and 100, and their sum has to be the total number of `X` columns. In other words, denoting these as h and k, one has to solve the middle school system h/40 = k/100, h+k=2. Naturally, I rounded the values found (which were not decimal numbers), with the constraint that their sum remain equal to 2.